# cmake error because of boost_thread missing

Tags: boost, cmake, point-cloud-library

i am trying to compile pcl and i have installed all of its dependencies.
But when I am trying cmake it gives an error stating boost_thread is missing.
i have tried
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON/OFF)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREAD ON/OFF)

i have checked my \usr\include folder. It contains boost folder in it and inside that there is thread folder but there is no lib named boost_thread in it.
and also in my \usr\lib there are all libraries but one liboost_thread.[image: screenshot of cmake error]

windows -ubuntu 16.04

pcl_source_code - https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/cmake/pcl_find_boost.cmake

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you don't have development version of boost thread library. Try `sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev`